# Comma before 'only to'

Tags: punctuation, commas

Can someone help me sort this one out, please? Should there be a comma before 'only to' in the following sentence?

> I went to the club, only to see Joel leaving.

Particulary, does a comma make the sentence less ambiguous:

- I went to the club in vain because Joel was leaving.
- I only went to the club for the purpose of seeing Joel leave.

Answer (score 5):

Bear in mind that punctuation is a matter of style, and as such you should be guided by your manual of style. There's no universal *should*, just conformance to the guide you have chosen or have had thrust upon you. I favor the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which would suggest placing the comma for three reasons --

1. You have a contrasting element, since the implication of the sentence is that you went to the club expecting to meet Joel. Your dashed expectation should be preceded by a comma.
2. As FumbleFingers notes in his comment, without the comma the sentence may have an entirely separate meaning, namely that the sole reason for your going to the club was to watch Joel leave.
3. Without the comma, you have a potential garden path, i.e, an invitation is mislead your reader into an incorrect parse, as in

   > I went to the club only, not the gym.

Comment: Actually, I'd have thought the default interpretation without the comma (or pause in speech) would be *The only reason I went to the club was so I could see Joel leave.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good catch. A third reason, which I will add to the answer.

Comment: I think both answers are now excellent. But then again, I already *know* the information being conveyed. I'd be interested to find out whether any learners who *couldn't* already see all the different interpretations find either answer significantly easier to understand than the other.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to help the reader properly parse what you're trying to say.  Compare:

> I went to the club, only to see Joel leaving.

(You went to the club, but Joel was just leaving, which dashed your hopes or was an impediment to your goal, which was probably to meet or spend more time with Joel.)

> I went to the club only, to see Joel leaving.

(Joel is a famous person and when he enters or leaves a place, crowds gather to see it.  You were in one of those crowds, but only at the club.)

> I went to the club only to see Joel leaving.

(Ambiguous which could cover either of the above, or something else, but most likely to have the first meaning above.)

Comment: Your third example wouldn't necessarily carry *either* of the two previous senses. Perhaps the only reason you went to the club was because you knew there was going to be a vote on whether or not to kick Joel out. Within which context there are *still* two possibilities: either you wanted to cast *your* vote to make sure he did in fact get voted out, or you knew the vote would go against him and you wanted to gloat over watching him be forced to leave.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Does the edit help?